# Copy field to another field, different rows, where id = parentID

Tags: mysql, string, copy, field, concatenation

I'm quite new to mysql and don't know that much, never the less I need to get some things done. :)

`bla bla`

I'm trying to figure out how to concat a string from one field, to the beginning of another. In the same table, but different rows. Using where id = parentID or such.
Check out my tables below, hopefully you'll understand.

My table:

```
table
id | textcol | extra_textcol | parentID
1  | 'text1' | NULL          | NULL
2  | NULL    | 'extratext2'  | 1
3  | 'text'  | NULL          | NULL
```

Result I'm trying to get:

```
table
id | textcol           | extra_textcol | parentID
1  | 'extratext2text1' | NULL          | NULL
2  | NULL              | 'extratext2'  | 1
3  | 'text'            | NULL          | NULL
```

Anyone out there who could help me with this?

**EDIT: Forgot to say, the result I want is from an UPDATE :D**

Comment: What you you have more than one record with `ParentId = 1`? What does you want to be in `textcol` for record `1` in this case?

Comment: I'm importing data from an old database to a new one. 
So new entries won't be needing this, since data will be entered to the textcol when a new entry is made. 
So I've got old data based on parts of extra_textcol that I need to moved to textcol.

Comment: you didn't answer the question. What you you have more than one record with `ParentId = 1`? What does you want to be in `textcol` for record `1` in this case?

Comment: @Quassnoi: Oh sorry, if there is more than one record with `ParentID = 1`, add it after the previous one, ASC. example (if id3 had extra_textcol = extratext3 and parentid = 1): `extratext2extratex3text1`. I noticed it added a comma between the records when I tried the query you showed below. I'm guessing the update won't have a problem with adding my own input in front of and after, such as `'BEFORE', mp.extra_textcol, 'AFTER'`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  mc.id, CONCAT(COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(mp.extra_textcol ORDER BY id SEPARATOR ''), ''), mc.textcol) AS textcol, mc.extra_textcol, parentID
FROM    mytable mc
LEFT JOIN
        mytable mp
ON      mp.ParentID = mc.id
GROUP BY
        mc.id
```

To make an update, you'll have to create a temporary table first, since `MySQL` won't let you use subqueries to the updated table in an update.

```
CREATE TABLE newtable (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, textcol TEXT) ENGINE=Memory
AS
SELECT  mc.id, CONCAT(COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(mp.extra_textcol ORDER BY id SEPARATOR ''), ''), mc.textcol) AS textcol, mc.extra_textcol, parentID
FROM    mytable mc
LEFT JOIN
        mytable mp
ON      mp.ParentID = mc.id
GROUP BY
        mc.id;

UPDATE  mytable m
JOIN    newtable n
ON      m.id = n.id
SET     m.textcol = n.textcol
```

If you have an out-of-memory error on `CREATE TABLE`, you'll have to use `MyISAM` instead of `Memory` storage engine.

Comment: Thanks alot. I'm getting an error though, "Column 'extra_textcol' in field list is ambiguous". I guess I should change it to something like mc.extra_textcol, mp.parentID?
And for update I just go with update mytable set .... ?

Comment: Uh, sorry. Should have mentioned I wanted to UPDATE the table with the new results. ^^; Any chance you could show me how to do such an update?